# Retaining Original Folder with GIT subdirectory-filter

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have the following folder structure:

```
Folder1
 -> SubDirectory1
   -> File1
   -> File2
 -> SubDirectory2
```

I need to filter the structure so that only SubDirectory1 and its contents are left.

I'm using:

```
git filter-branch -f --subdirectory-filter "Folder1/SubDirectory1" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

The problem is SubDirectory1 folder is also being removed and I need that. What switch do I use to retain the SubDirectory1 folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can split history by specific folder by:

```
git subtree split -P Folder1/SubDirectory1 --rejoin --branch new-split-branch
```

Then move folder into its original location:

```
git checkout new-split-branch
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mkdir -p Folder1/SubDirectory1 && git mv -vk * Folder1/SubDirectory1/ || true'
```